# image_tag gives different result for the same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically I have

```
= image_tag('procedure_icons/chemical/chemical.png')
```

which gives expected result, proper `html`

```
<img src="/assets/procedure_icons/chemical/chemical-7eee22622b56126c0339a1c340bd4708ca689031ea6448a132c5c004beb32e78.png" alt="Chemical">
```

but when I try something like this

```
= image_tag(object.icon_path)
```

where `icon_path` is draper decorator method

```
def icon_path
  "/procedure_icons/#{object.icon_type}/#{object.icon_type}.png"
end
```

generated `html` is different

```
<img src="/procedure_icons/chemical/chemical.png" alt="Chemical">
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `image_tag` is being passed `'procedure_icons/chemical/chemical.png'` which the asset pipeline can recognize and thus the source is the image as processed by the asset pipeline.

The second `image_tag` is being passed `'/procedure_icons/chemical/chemical.png'` which is just telling rails to use the specific path passed into the helper (notice the proceeding backslash)

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't noticed this gentle difference.